# android asynchronous sockets (android app as server waiting for clients to connect)

Tags: android, sockets, networking, asynchronous, nio

im trying to implement a tcp socket connection between an android app (as server) and a java based client running on windows. *(short version below, without code)*

Im using some sensor listener to implement a game movement (everybody knows this sensor based movement of racing games.

Ive implemented a service for that purpose, which is started out of the first activity. This service is implemented as follows (im just pasting the relevant code snippets, not the whole class):

```
public class ServerService extends Service {

    ConnectionHandler conHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        startListener();
    }

    private void startListener() {
        conHandler = new ConnectionHandler(this);
        conHandler.execute();
    }

    private void sendMessage(String s)
    {
        conHandler.write(s);
    }

    public void messageNotify(String s) {
        //Log.d("receivedMessage", s);
    }    
}
```

The ConnectionHandler class:

```
public class ConnectionHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    public static int serverport = 11111;
    ServerSocket s;
    Socket c;
    ConnectionListening conListening;
    ConnectionWriting conWriting;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream dis;
    ServerService server;

    public ConnectionHandler(ServerService server)
    {
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Creating Socket");
            s = new ServerSocket(serverport);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Cannot create Socket");
        }
        try {
                    //this is blocking until client connects
            c = s.accept();
            Log.d("ConnectionHandler", "client connected");
            dis = new DataInputStream(c.getInputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
            conWriting = new ConnectionWriting(this.c, this.dos);
            conWriting.execute();
            conListening = new ConnectionListening(this.c, this.dis, this.server);
            if(this.c != null)
            {
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(conListening, 0, 10);
            }

            Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Socket created, Streams assigned");
        return null;
    }

    public void write(String s)
    {
        conWriting.writeToStream(s);
    }

    public void messageNotify(String s) {
        // TODO method stub 
    }   

}
```

The ConnectionHandler ist implemented as AsyncTask similarly to the ConnectionWriting, so that the blocking of tcp methods doenst affect the whole communication.
The client is able to send messages to the server to. Because i dont know when this messages will arrive, im using a TimerTask which is executed every 10ms, to check if there is a new message.

ConnectionWriting looks as follows:

```
public class ConnectionWriting extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean>{

    public DataOutputStream dos;
    Socket c;

    public ConnectionWriting(Socket c, DataOutputStream dos) {
        this.dos = dos;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
        return true;
    }   

    public void writeToStream(String s) {
        try {
            if (c != null){
                //Log.i("AsynkTask", "writeToStream");
                dos.writeBytes(s+"\n");
                dos.flush();
                Log.i("AsynkTask", "write: " +s);
            } else {
                Log.i("AsynkTask", "writeToStream : Cannot write to stream, Socket is closed");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("AsynkTask", "writeToStream : Writing failed");
        }
    }

}
```

And the ConnectionListening class:
    public class ConnectionListening extends TimerTask{

```
    public DataInputStream dis;
    Socket c;
    ServerService server;

    public ConnectionListening(Socket c, DataInputStream dis, ServerService server)
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.dis = dis;
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String message = "";
        try {
            if (c != null) {
                //Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : Reading message");
                message = dis.readLine();
                Log.i("AsynkTask", "read: " + message);
            } else {
                Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : Cannot Read, Socket is closed");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : Writing failed");
        }

        if(message != null)
        {
            this.server.messageNotify(message);
        }

    }


}
```

I choose this complex, asynchronous way because the server is almost continuous sending data to the client and there are situations where the client has to send data back.
With the traditional way of using tcp sockets, it is not possible to realise a non blocking communication, so that means if the server is sending (writing), the read function blocks and i will never get the client message.

**to keep it short:**
Ive tested my approach but the server is always sending his data first and then getting the client messages. It is not asynchronous!? :-/

Maybe anybody can help me to solve this problem.
Or is there even a simpler way to implement that approach?
It is necessary that the communication is asynchronous! And the read has to be done automatically (what i tried to implement with this polling approach).

Ive read that i can use a single thread for the reading and one for the writing, but then i have a problem with using the write functionality (dont know how to call a function in a running thread) and with calling functions in my activities.

Im thankful for every help!

regards

Comment: nobody who can help here? :-/

Comment: look at this thread to see how ive solved the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650193/android-asynchronous-sockets